# How to replace columns of one csv with the columns from other csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have two CSVs

*one.csv*

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
```

*two.csv*

```
6,7,4,5
7,8,10,15
```

I have to replace the last two columns from the first file with the last two columns of the second file and output files should be

```
1,2,4,5
5,6,10,15
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you've tried so far: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv(csv1,usecols=[1,2,3,4 5,6], names=[1,2,3,4 5,6] header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv(csv2,usecols=[10,15], names=[10,15] header=None)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

EDIT: In response to your comment with different dimensions than the question: Load both dataframes in full, drop last two on the first one then use `df.ix[row slice, column slice]` to slice the second dataframe (like: `df.ix[:,'b':]`) in order to get just the last [n] columns you want, concatenate using `pd.concat` and you should have your desired output

Comment: It looks like you are using pandas.  You might want to include the import to make that explicit

Comment: added the import, i just assumed since pandas was a tag.

Comment: Actually , i have a row with 86 columns in which only three has to be replaced . Rest all should be intact. This code is just givng me a new file with replaced values

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
In [10]: (pd.read_csv(fn1, header=None, usecols=[0,1])
   ....:    .join(pd.read_csv(fn2, header=None, usecols=[2,3])))
Out[10]:
   0  1   2   3
0  1  2   4   5
1  5  6  10  15
```

save back to csv:

```
In [11]: (pd.read_csv(fn1, header=None, usecols=[0,1])
   ....:    .join(pd.read_csv(fn2, header=None, usecols=[2,3]))
   ....:    .to_csv('c:/temp/result.csv', index=False, header=None)
   ....: )
```

result.csv

```
1,2,4,5
5,6,10,15
```